# Calling a jQuery function with parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a btn

```
<a href="#" id="submitBtn" class="btnGray">Upload Docs</a>
```

and a jquery code to submit the form.

```
$("#docSaveBtn").click(function(){
  $("#docForm").submit();                           
});
```

I have multiple forms on the same page and I want to send the form id to submit which will submit the desired form when click of button with class 'btnGray'.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Your code appears to submit in response to the press of a button with the id `docSaveBtn`, while your markup references a *link* with an id of `submitBtn` and your description appears to talk about the same... What do you actually intend to occur?

Comment: @Aanu I've provided two alternatives that I think will provide nicer code that is easier to maintain. I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @jonathan - there's a bit cleaner of a way than what you're recommending... see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Custom data attributes

One ideal solution would be to use custom data attributes on the anchor itself, informing jQuery which form should be submitted when the anchor is clicked.

```
<a data-form="bears">Submit Bears</a>
<form id="bears"></form>
```

In the above example, we're stating that we would like our anchor to have an association with our form that immediately follows. Now we provide the logic via jQuery:

```
$("a[data-form]").on("click", function(e){
    var formName = $(this).data("form");
    $("#" + formName).submit();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/65HPj/

#### Proximity-based Submission...

A much cleaner solution would be proximity-based, where a link submits it's closest form:

```
$(".submitBtn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".linkFormBlock").find("form").submit();
});
```

```
<div class="linkFormBlock">
  <a href="submitBtn">Upload Docs</a>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="specialValues" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonathan, Thanks!. It worked. I used the rel - solution. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

$(".btnGray").click(function(){ $("#docForm").submit();});

Comment: I am not sure if this would help. In this case I would have to write this for each form. I guess I should rephrase my question. I want to submit a particular form based on the form Id I send onClick of a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `submit()` method, you could just include any relevant parameters in your `action` attribute of your `form` tag. e.g:

```
<form action="/formProcessor.aspx?id=1234">
....
    <a href="#" id="submitBtn" class="btnGray">Upload Docs</a>
....
</form>
```

Using the jQuery you supplied in your question, this will automatically submit your form using the action designated in your `form` tag.